# How to copy EXIF metadata on Android from one photo to another?

Tags: metadata, exiftool, android, apps, mobile

I'm looking for a way to copy some (say date, location, camera) or all EXIF metadata from one image to another image **on Android**, so I can restore metadata deleted by some photo editing apps.

I recently moved to a mobile workflow. I use an Android smartphone to sort, edit and publish or share photos taken with my DSLR and my smartphone. Some of the apps I use to edit my shots remove EXIF metadata.

I understand that this may be intentional, since date or location can be meaningless in apps such as *Photoshop Mix* or *Instagram Layout*, since they let you compose several different images together. The problem is that the missing metadata break my classification system when I import those photos later on a computer.

On a computer I'd use `exiftool` to restore those metadata, using a command like:

```
exiftool -tagsfromfile orig.jpg -exif new.jpg
```

Is there an app **for Android** or a web service I can use to copy metadata as I can do with `exiftool`?

Comment: I haven't used the app but take a look at [FastPhotoTagger](http://fastphototagger.sourceforge.net/a/fastphototagger.html).  The docs seem to imply you can copy metadata between files.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but doesn't seem possible to copy metadata using that app (or, at least, I couldn't find a way to do it).

Comment: The [Compare Metadata](http://fastphototagger.sourceforge.net/a/fastphototagger.html#Using_Compare_Metadata) command seems to be able copy info, but then it doesn't look like it would be easy for bulk data copying.

Comment: I found a port of exiftool for android that solves my problem, but it's not as comfortable and friendly as one expects on mobile. So I posted and answer, but for the moment I won't mark is as accepted - maybe someones else can still find better solutions: https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/97092/20180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found on the Google Play Store a port for Android of `exiftool`, named (no surprise)  [ExifTool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.al.exiftool), that gives you a command line interface to the well known tool.

It's not as comfortable and quick as one would expect from a mobile app, but it works.

**Workflow:**

1. Tap on the 3 dots menu and  choose `Execute command`
2. Type or paste `exiftool -tagsfromfile  source  -exif  dest` (after the first time it could "remember" your last command, so you may only need to replace the file names)
3. Move the cursor to `source`, delete it.
4. If you know the full file path  you can just paste or type it, or you can tap 3 dots menu and then `Add path to file` and use android system file chooser to pick the photo you want to **copy the tags from**.
5. Move the cursor to `dest`, delete it.
6. Again, add the file path or tap the 3 dots menu and then `Add path to file` and use android system file chooser to pick the photo you want to **copy the tags to**.
7. Tap the triangle icon to run the command and wait for the confirmation window.

[image: ExifTool app screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround that is not optimal for your problem but better than nothing.

You can tell [A Photo Manager](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki) to store meta data changes in jpg and in external xmp file. When your external app deletes the meta from jpg the info is still present in the xmp file and can be restored from there.

Note only the [7 most important meta fields DateTimeTaken Latitude Longitude Title Description Tags Rating](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki/Metadata) are supported

Workflow:

- In [A Photo Manager settings](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki/settings) under Edit set "Write changes to "jpg and xmp (create if not found)
- In [A Photo Manager gallery view](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki/Gallery-View) select all images
- Ad some dummy Tag to all images. As a side effect the xmp-s are generated.
- do something that deletes the exif from jpg
- In [A Photo Manager gallery view](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki/Gallery-View) select all images
- Ad some other dummy Tag to all images or remove the dummy tag. As a side effect the meta data is read from jpg/xmp-s and the changes are writen to jpg and xmp (restoring jpg meta data)

Comment: Interesting solution, not as easy and smooth as I hoped, but seems to work. Thanks!